# It is possible to retrieve only the text from a mail using Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, text

I want to know if there is a way to retrieve the text from a mail using a function similar to mail->render. I want to retrieve the text without the html, in a way that the text has the same structure break lines as the html.

[image]

```php
$body_text = strip_tags($body_html,"<style>");
        $substring = substr($body_text,strpos($body_text,"<style"),strpos($body_text,"</style>")+2);
        $body_text = str_replace($substring,"",$body_text);
        $body_text = trim($body_text);
        $body_text = str_replace(array("\t","\r","\n"),"",$body_text);
```

I've tried doing this, but it returns the text aglomerated all together. I want to have the text like the photo.

Comment: With that last line, you're removing the line breaks.  Perhaps you want to keep them?

Comment: @RobEyre if it really is a HTML mail then they wouldn't have any effect anyway

Comment: @rippleytrigger you should try to understand that a rendered email isn't a piece of text. It's the result of interpreting the HTML and CSS and turning that into a graphical display. If you literally got out the raw text without any HTML around it, then it would have no formatting information and just be one long stream of text. Therefore your aim to have "the text without the HTML but still with the line breaks" is a contradiction. There's no such thing. What exactly are you wanting to do with it, once you've got this mythical piece of data? Perhaps there's a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: If your message has an actual inline text/plain part, then you can use the [getTextContent()](https://mail-mime-parser.org/api/2.4/classes/ZBateson-MailMimeParser-IMessage.html#method_getTextContent) method of [zbateson/mail-mime-parser](https://github.com/zbateson/mail-mime-parser) for this. Out of curiosity, which mail faker are you using here? Looks a lot like Mailpit but I don't have a spam analysis tab on mine, that would be handy.